# Rails - Why are my comments not rendering?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For my application, I am currently listing my projects related to a user on the user's page.  For each project listed, I want to render the comments made for each project. I am able to post comments to each project to the database via the form, but unable to render the comments related to the comments. Nothing renders. I have been playing around with the users_controller thinking it is there with no success. How do I fix it?

I have created models and controllers for Users, Projects, and Comments. Comments belong to Projects and Projects belong to Users.

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "comments", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "project_id"
  t.text     "content"
  t.datetime "created_at",    :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",    :null => false
end
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :projects
has_many :comments
```

**project.rb**

```
has_many :comments
belongs_to :user
```

**comment.rb**

```
belongs_to :project
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :users 

resources :projects do
  resources :comments 
end

resources: comments
```

**view/users/_projects.html.erb**

```
<%= render @projects %>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def comments
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @projects = @user.projects.newest.page(params[:comments_page]).per_page(10)
  @project = Project.new
  @comments = Project.find(params[:id]).comments.newest.page(params[:comments_page]).per_page(2)
end
```

**view/projects/_project.html.erb**

```
<%= project.content %>
<%= render 'comments/form', project:project %>
<%= render @comments %>
<%= will_paginate @comments, :param_name => 'comments_page' %>
```

**view/comments/_comment.html.erb**

```
<%= comment.content %>
```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

Comment: In routes.rb, I suppose your first block would be enough. In projects.html.erb, what is this render suppose to do? In users_controller, you are defining @project 2 times one after another... which doesn't seem to be on purpose.

Comment: You're using the same params[:id] to find your user and the project for @commemts.

Comment: I tried using :comments_id but get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your project.html.erb file try using a loop like so:

```
<% project.comments.each do |c| %>
  #do something
<% end %>
```